# jQuery select LI above element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to select the list item above a button and change its parent's `background-color` to red.

```
    <li>red bg on click <input class="addtocart" value="press" name="button"></li>
    <li>red bg on click <input class="addtocart" value="press" name="button"></li>
    <li>red bg on click <input class="addtocart" value="press" name="button"></li>
    <li>red bg on click <input class="addtocart" value="press" name="button"></li>
```

jQuery so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".addtocart").click( function(){
     $('li').parent().css('background-color', 'red');
  });
});
```

From what I can see it looks correct, but it seems to be changing a different element's `background-color`.

Thanks

Comment: "I'm trying to *select the list item* above a button and *change its parents* background color." I'm sorry, you're trying to change the `background-color` of the `li` or the parent `ol` or `ul`? (The way your sentence is constructed makes it *look* like the subject should be the parent of the `li`, but your HTML only shows the `li` elements.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `this`

```
$(this).parent().css('background-color', 'red');
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

      $(".addtocart").click( function()
           {
             $(this).closest('li').css('background-color', 'red');
           }
      );
});
```

Comment: Is there anyway I can select the actually list item its in, because on my working project it has a deeper structure?

Comment: @Stano  sorry, what are you talking about?

Comment: @Stano its following OP's comment here, have you read it? BTW, could be parents('li').first() but i prefer closest(), just my personnal feeling

Comment: `.closest()` is useful if you are binding events to grand children and want to lookup to the parent.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is wrong . Try to use `this` for current element

When you use  `$('li')` it will apply to all `li` elements

```
$(this).parent().c....
```

Answer (score 1):

You need current clicked element

```
$(this).parent().css('background-color', 'red');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Pmdub/)

Answer (score 1):

Try to change to this:

```
$(this).parent().css('background-color', 'red');
```